# Dynamically Adding Compounds to Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, fragment

**Found the solution, see answer below**

tl;dr - My `View` from the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` is fine, but the result shown in the app is not. WTF?

**I am new to Android.** I am developing a single-activity Android app with some tabs managed by a TabLayout. The contents are Fragments displayed in a ViewPager. My activity_main.xml looks as follows:

```
<!-- SIMPLIFIED VERSION -->
<LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm using a [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html/) which keeps the Fragments alive all the time (contrary to [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html)), but destroys the View when the Fragment cannot be reached by the user from the current position. This means, that if the user is on the outer left tab, all tabs past the second tab from the left exist as a Fragment, but have no View. This seems counter-intuitive, as the user could just click on the tab he wants and reach ANY Fragment at all time, but I understand that the FragmentPagerAdapter only sees the ViewPager (which is navigated through swiping), not the TabLayout.

As the fragments Views get created, `onCreateView()` is called. When the View is detroyed, `onDestroyView()` is called. My Fragments are rather simple:

```
<!-- SIMPLIFIED VERSION -->
<LinearLayout>
  <ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
      <!-- I want to dynamically add Views here -->
    </LinearLayout>
  <ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
```

Now, I have a bunch ob objects in the background representing some data. When the Fragment gets a View (`onCreateView()`), I want to add custom Views for each data item into the Fragment. This should end up looking like a vertical list. I already instantiated the Views to be added in `onCreate()`. This seems logical to me, as `onCreate()` is only called once in my whole app.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // The fragment UI
    _me = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_log, container, false);

    // LinearLayout inside the ScrollView
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) _me.findViewById(R.id.scrollableLinearLayout);

    // Already instantiated CompoundViews
    for(LogEntryCompound compound: _logEntryCompounds) {
        l.addView(compound);
        // My method to populate all TextViews, etc. from compound._data
        compound.refreshUI();
    }

    return _me;
}
```

Since the view of the fragments gets destroyed, but not the fragment itself, this is done every time the user swipes too far from this fragment. I don't get this part completely (see my list of questions below), but it seems that when `onCreateView()` is called again later, the Compounds I already added are still there. Therefore I remove all Views in the Fragments' `onDetroyView()`:

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) _me.findViewById(R.id.scrollableLinearLayout);
    l.removeAllViews();
}
```

The Compounds I display are sort of like Tiles, have some TextViews, ProgressBars, and are clickable. They directly represent a data object. All things they display come from this data directly (each Compound has a reference to his `_data`). I set all relevant UI elements within these Compounds by calling `refreshUI()`:

```
public void refreshUI() {
    _txtName.setText(_data.getName());
    _txtDescr.setText(_data.getDescription());
    _txtTopRight.setText(_data.getTimeString());
    ...
}
```

**Now I have a really weird problem**: All _data objects behave as they should, all the data is correct, even the Compounds' UI Elements have the correct `.text` set. The view I return in `onCreateView` is perfectly fine. But the View then shown in the app is not. Three out of four TextViews are fine, but one shows the same value for all 'Tiles' im displaying. The value displayed would be the correct value only for the LAST Tile.

Additionally, I have some more general questions (and I assume the more experienced readers will already be on their toes to tell me) about how things SHOULD be done:

**1.** Can I get the FragmentPagerAdapter to behave in a way that the views of the fragments are never destroyed? It's only three tabs and not a horrendeous amount of data. Recreating the View every time is surely inefficient?

**2.** How exactly does the FragmentPagerAdapter/ViewPager work? Why is it, that even though the View is apparently destroyed, it still contains the children I added before it got destroyed?

**3.** Should I add my Compounds anywhere else in code? Does the `onCreateView()` automagiacally restores its previous state? Or is `onCreate()` for instantiation and `onCreateView()` for adding to the UI correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some late night debugging and code review I had a look at my XML file for the 'Tile'-View in question. For the TextView that behaved weirdly I found this:

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Removed it - everything works like a charm now.

Can't really explain this. Can only imagine that maybe the fact that the view is selectable, android messes up something and sees the TextViews from all Tiles as one and thus showing the same text across all.